# Why ZMQ XPUB/XSUB zmq_proxy reconnects in about 20 minutes after XPUB changed it's IP?

Tags: proxy, zeromq

I'm dealing with a **`XPUB`**/**`XSUB`** zmq_proxy with the next architecture. Some publishers (**`PUB`**) connect to the proxy and some subscribers (**`SUB`**) receive message from publishers through the proxy.

The publisher is running in a not reliable network and sometimes change the IP address. When that occurs the `XPUB`/`XSUB` connection is down till more or less 20 minutes, when it reconnects.

Anybody knows where comes these 20 minutes? A TCP/IP timeout?

Comment: I've founded a possible workarrond to minimize this time. The kernel variable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2 was at its default value: 15. That's mean 924.6 seconds of timeout on alive TCP connections, when RTO retransmissions remain unacknoledged. (see (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)